# How to use Cluster singlton or Cluster sharding in Akka-Cluster for million individual Actors?

Tags: akka, akka.net, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor

I have a use case where a million individual actors will be created across the cluster.
The tasks will be received from outside cluster and i have to identify and send the task to assigned single actor for that task.

> How can i create actor from outside of the cluster if i use Cluster sharding and how to send message to that particular actor  from outside of the cluster nodes

If i use Cluster sharding i have to create seperate shard for a actor.Which means

> Million shards have to created for million actors.

How to identify the shard and actor in cluster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle million individual actors with AKKA Cluster setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057627/how-to-handle-million-individual-actors-with-akka-cluster-setup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i use Cluster sharding i have to create seperate shard for a actor.

A shard is just a local grouping of actors that are all hosted in the same process - it's an arbitrary way of grouping entity actors together in Akka.NET. Typically we use consistent hashing (`HashCodeMessageExtractor`) to assign entity actors to a shard based on the entity actor's unique id, which you extract from the content of the messages sent to it via the `ShardRegion` and the `IMessageExtractor` (most commonly, a `HashCodeMessageExtractor`).

This is a great tool for being able to distribute millions of actors horizontally across a large cluster - I just published a sample the other day where I was running 200 Akka.NET nodes with 2000 total shards (10 per node) with the ability to host 10s of millions of actors: https://github.com/petabridge/AkkaDotNet.LargeNetworkTests - you might find that helpful!

Comment: When a message arrives can we send it to particular Actor in a shard? How it will happen automatically for every message?

Comment: The `IMessageExtractor` will extract a unique identity from all messages sent to the `ShardRegion` - all messages belonging to the same unique identity are sent to the same actor.

Comment: How to get that shardRegion actor reference from a node outside the cluster?

Comment: You'd need to have the nodes outside the cluster message actors that are inside it, and the actors inside the cluster can communicate with the `ShardRegion` via the `ShardRegion IActorRef` itself or via a `ShardRegionProxy`.